# stepSize is not working in chart js for line chart x-axis

Tags: javascript, chart.js

So i have a line chart in Chartjs, my X axis looks like this.

```
scales: {
  xAxes: [{
    display: true,
    ticks: {
      maxTicksLimit: 7
    }
  }],
```

When i do this, i get the appopriate number of items on the X axis.   But the last grid mark is always way wider than the others, and i cant figure out what setting im missing.  As you can see the first 6 timestamps are evenly spaced, then the last one is way  off on the right side.  I've tried larger, smaller, even, odd settings for maxTicksLimit but i still have this issue and its killing the perfectionist in me looking at it.

[image]

Comment: Try specify the X axis type as `time` - `type: 'time'` http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html

Comment: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#scale-distribution `'linear': data are spread according to their time (distances can vary) - 'series': data are spread at the same distance from each other`

Comment: @pokeybit `autoSkip: false,` makes equal grid

Comment: @pokeybit When i try setting it to type: time and distribution: series, i end up with a blank graph and a single time on the far left.  What are they expecting for that to work?  My array is an array of JS Date() that is converted from Unix timestamps using  toLocalTimeString('en-US')

Comment: @user1024792 are you placing those parameters in the right part, show the code that produces blank chart please

Comment: This answer show how to solve this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63646986/2358409