# ChartJS have xAxes labels match data source

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I've got this graph xAxes set to:

```
xAxes: [{
    ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        suggestedMin: 0,
    },
    type: 'time',
    time: {
        stepSize: 1,
        unit: 'week',
        displayFormats: {
            day: CHART_AXIS_DATE_FORMAT,
            week: CHART_AXIS_DATE_FORMAT,
        },
    },
}]
```

I've played around with `source` setting it to label/data, tried playing around with the step size and beginAtZero, nothing seems to work, basically i just want the same functionality i have in the graph but the dates starting from the first datapoint

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The ticks appear at the begin of each `time.unit`. When choosing `time.unit: 'week'`, in your case, the ticks appear on each Sunday, also because `time.stepSize` defaults to `1`.

There's probably no predefined single option that allows you to obtain what you're looking for. You can however solve the problem as follows:

1. Generate and define the `data.labels` you want to see on the x-axis.
2. Define the option `ticks.source: 'labels'` for the x-axis.

Please take y look at this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63646986/2358409) that deals with a similar issue.